# Silverlight OOB Splash Screen

Tags: silverlight, splash-screen, silverlight-oob, out-of-browser

In my Silverlight 5 OOB main method I'm setting a custom Application.Current.MainWindow.Left and Application.Current.MainWindow.Top. 
When starting the application the OOB window appears briefly at the default position which is set in the OutOfBrowserSettings.xml. How can I prevent this? I want something like a custom splash screen for OOB.

Answer (score -1):

You could try starting it full screen to show the splash screen, then resize it to your desired settings.